# Jquery Enable/Disable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to make this code work when the page has more than 1 group of datepicker.

If you select the option "I currently work here" it affects both groups and I wanted to affect only the current group.

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/bps3Lha5/)

```
$('.current-work-status').change(function () {
    $('.form-control-2').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('.current-work-status').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').prev().find('.form-control-2').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

**[updated fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/bps3Lha5/7/)**

Comment: Thank you mate and thank you all for the solutions! That worked. I will mark this one as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Try

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bps3Lha5/2/)

Use jQuery [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) selector to find parent of group and using [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) get `.form-control-2` and update attribute.

```
$('.current-work-status').change(function () {
   $(this).parents('div.row').find('.form-control-2').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: @BhupendraShukla parent only check for first parent dive not more then that .. and i use `parents` not `closest ` .